# "His amazing achievement all bottles down to the support and guidance"--what's the meaning of 'bottle down'?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

This sentence confused me ([source](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/abdulrahman-hussain-egypt-boy-smartest-child-world-mensa-clever-intelligence-a8139441.html)):

> Hussain spoke to Al Arabiya after his victory, saying that his amazing achievement **all bottles down to** the support and guidance that he’s received from his teachers and family.

I was wondering what is the meaning of *bottles down*.

Answer (score 2):

People usually "bottle up", but "boil down".

"Bottling up" usually refers to keeping emotions or feelings inside yourself instead of dealing with them.

"Boil down" means to simplify something to its base elements.  Often it is used to describe that something complex "boils down to" something more simple.

I assume that people will infer that "bottle down" was actually a reference to "boil down".

Comment: Can we say that boils down, to a certain extent, means: Because of

Answer (score 1):

Bottle down means to quell an emotion or feeling. See *[1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four)*

> The Party needed in its members be kept at the right pitch, except by **bottling down** some powerful instinct.